# Beautiful soup returning 'p' nodes after a node

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python 3.6 and beautfulsoup4

I have the first node:

`title = self.html.find(id=(lists[1][selectionindex]))`

this is not none and is this node is highlighted in red:

[image]

How can i get a list of the nodes in blue (any div/p nodes) but stop when it gets to h1/2/3 node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you can find the first `<h3>` tag using some `id` (as shown in your code). The following code will get all the `<p>` and `<div>` tags after the `<h3>` tag and will stop when it encounters either `<h1>`, `<h2>` or an `<h3>` tag.

```
html = '''
<p>unwanted</p>
<h3 id="special">some text</h3>
<div class="foo">wanted</div>
<p>wanted</p>
<p>wanted</p>
<p>wanted</p>
<h2>some text</h2>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

list_of_wanted_tags = []
starting_tag = soup.find('h3', id='special')

for tag in starting_tag.find_all_next():
    if tag.name in ('div', 'p'):
        list_of_wanted_tags.append(tag)
    elif tag.name in ('h1', 'h2', 'h3'):
        break

print(list_of_wanted_tags)
# [<div class="foo">wanted</div>, <p>wanted</p>, <p>wanted</p>, <p>wanted</p>]
```

The [**`find_all_next()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method returns a list of all the tags that come after the current tag.

---

If you want all the tags between two such tags, and not only the `<p>` and `<div>` tags, use this:

```
for tag in starting_tag.find_all_next():
    if tag.name in ('h1', 'h2', 'h3'):
        break
    list_of_wanted_tags.append(tag)
```

Or, the same using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
wanted = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda tag: tag.name not in ('h1', 'h2', 'h3'), start.find_all_next()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup's `find_all` function to get all instances of a specific HTML tag.

```
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.google.co.uk')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

f = soup.find_all("p")

for p in f:
    print p
```

Comment: however this will get all the 'p' tags in the file. As you can see in my description i clearly state i want the 'p' and div files between the red and green tag not all the p files.

Comment: What's stopping you from using a simple `for` loop between the `h3` and `h2` tags then and simply checking the tag?